# PHP: detect if we are inside an outer try..catch block

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

Is possible to tell if we are inside an external try..catch block or not?

Example code (please take is **just** as an example):

```
<?php
class Foo{
    public function load($id)
    {
        try{
            // Model throw NodeNotFoundException only in rare cases
            $node = $this->getModel()->loadById($id);
        }
        catch(NodeNotFoundException $nle)
        {
            // @here I need to tell if im in the First case or in the Second one,
            // detecting the external try..catch block
            if(externalTryCatchBlock() === true)
            {
                throw $nle;
            }
            else
            {
                watchdog('Unable to find node', $nle->details);
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            watchdog('Something gone wrong.');
            return null;
        }
        return $node;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();

// First case, no external try..catch 
$node = $foo->load(2);

// Second case: we need to do here something different if the node load
// throw an exception
try{
    $another_node = $foo->load(3);
}
catch(NodeNotFoundException $nle)
{
    watchdog('Unable to find node, using default.');
    $another_node = Bar::defaultNode(); // This is JUST for example
}

// Do something with $another_node
?>
```

Basically, I need to re-thrown the exception (`NodeNotFoundException`) only if there is another catch block waiting for it, to avoid the `Fatal error: Uncaught exception`.

Of course I could, for the examble above, use 2 load methods (one with and another w/o try..catch) but I would like to avoid this.. and I'm curious to know if is possible to detect try..catch blocks in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the job of a piece of code to worry about how it is called. The code throws an exception, always, end of story. Thereby the code has the "attribute" *may throw exception x*:

```
/**
 * Does something.
 *
 * @return mixed Some value.
 * @throws SomeException if something went wrong.
 */
function foo() {
   ...
}
```

Now, whoever calls this code needs to be prepared for it to throw an exception at any time. It is not up to the code to worry about whether somebody can catch the exception. If there's an exceptional situation, it throws an exception because it cannot continue to do its job. The *caller* needs to be prepared for this, not the other way around.

Comment: As I said before this is just an example, and a curiosity that came into my mind. By the way, we can have different kinds of exceptional situation - for the example above, if the node is not found is an error, but if the node is a field of another entity that pretend that node to exists we must do something else.

Comment: Having said this I do not *know* whether there's a sane programmatic way to figure out whether you are in a `try..catch` block or not, but I don't think there is. For the above cited reasons it sounds like a bad idea to have something like this and I've never heard of it.